# Display several sequences of events with possible line break in middle

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I am a HTML / CSS newbie.

I need to do something like this:

My web page is receiving sequences of events dynamically and I would like to visualize them on in the page.

I would like one sequence of events to be in a box, with lots of slots, and each slot has the event id.

So if I have several sequences, then I will have several such boxes.

However, the length of a sequence is dynamic. And the web page's window might be adjusted by the users, so even for a sequence, if it is too long or the window is too narrow, I have to break the box into several lines.

[image]

the above is my drawing of the design.

The `A`, `B`, etc, are the sequence title, then the numbers are the ids.

ideally, the space of all events / sequences should be as compact as possible.

And if a box has to change line, then it should be half-borded to indicate the continuous.

How can I do that? using CSS 3?

And also the framework I am using is AngularJS to control the data / UI binding, even if I manage to handle this case, how to dynamically bind the data to adjust this requirement?

Thanks

Comment: One approach is to have random background colors to each sequence blocks i.e `[A|1|2|3]` something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/or7a4xn5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in CSS is tricky, because you want a border between elements *only* if those elements are on the same line.  CSS doesn't know anything about wrapping.

I've solved the problem by:

1. Adding a left border on all boxes
2. Adding a right border on the last box only.
3. Adding a -1px left margin on all boxes *except* the first.
4. Placing the boxes in a container with `overflow: hidden`.

Having the right border on the last box only solves the right-hand issue.

The -1px left margin solves the left-hand issue.

**Snippet:**

```css
.sequences {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sequence > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sequence > div:last-of-type {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.sequence > div:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.yellow div {background: yellow;     width: 100px;}
.green div  {background: lightgreen; width: 80px;}
.blue div   {background: lightblue;  width: 120px;}
```

```html
<div class="sequences">
  <div class="sequence yellow">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sequence green">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sequence blue">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using CSS by doing something like this.
I've given each sequence element a top, left and bottom border. T
This will give the illusion of a right border when the elements are floated next to eachother but when they're the last on that line it will brake of as per your request.

I also added a right border to the last div element and the last div in each section.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h6Lw59h/2/)

```css
div{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    float:left; 
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div.last{margin-right: 5px;}

div.last,
div:last-child{border-right-width: 1px;}
```

```html
<div class="seq-1">1</div>
<div class="seq-1">2</div>
<div class="seq-1">3</div>
<div class="seq-1">4</div>
<div class="seq-1 last">5</div>
<div class="seq-2">1</div>
<div class="seq-2">2</div>
<div class="seq-2 last">3</div>
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed you wan't the border to be 0px/blank on the last element and the first element each row. Now that is a bit trickier.

I'm not positive there's a good solution to solving that using css since your sequences seem to be dynamic.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you need to use javascript to manage this.

**Edit 2: CSS and JQuery solution**

I made a quick jquery solution that utilies my previously provided CSS code.
The jQuery script removes the left border if the elements left offset(within it's parent) is 0 **and** if the element is not the first element in each sequenc(`first` class added).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhwhn15h/6/)

```js
var containerOffset = $('.container').offset().left;
setBorderWidth();

$(window).resize(function(){
    setBorderWidth();
});

function setBorderWidth(){
    $('.block').each(function() {
        var childOffset = $(this).offset().left;
        
        if(childOffset - containerOffset == 0 && !$(this).hasClass('first'))
            $(this).css("border-left-width", "0px");
        else
             $(this).css("border-left-width", "1px");
        
     });
}
```

```css
.container{width: 100%;}
.block{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px; 
    text-align: center; 
    float:left; 
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-width: 1px 0 1px 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.block.last{margin-right: 5px;}

.block.last,
.block:last-child{border-right-width: 1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="seq-1 block first">1</div>
    <div class="seq-1 block">2</div>
    <div class="seq-1 block">3</div>
    <div class="seq-1 block">4</div>
    <div class="seq-1 block last">5</div>
    <div class="seq-2 block first">1</div>
    <div class="seq-2 block">2</div>
    <div class="seq-2 block last">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to have 3 CSS classes
1) beginning of sequence
2) middle of sequence
3) end of sequence
then display different borders using:

```
  .beginning-of-seq {
      border-top-style: solid;
      border-right-style: none;
      border-bottom-style: solid;
      border-left-style: solid;
  }
```

for instance.

about the angular part just use ng-repeat="seq in sequences" for instance and then render the sequence with the classes you created so it will look good (of course you need the scope to have the sequences)

```
<span ng-repeat="seq in sequences">
  <span class="beginning-of-seq"> {{seq.title}} </span>
    <span class="middle-of-seq ng-repeat="elem in seq.otherElements">{{elem}}</span>
 <span class="end-of-seq"> {{seq.lastElem}} </span>
 </span>
</span>
```

this is a bit crude and i don't know how you implemented it but it should give you an idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

This HTML/CSS should do the trick. As you mentioned about the user having different resolutions, I've used percentages for the widths (depending on your scenario, media queries may be needed).

```css
.container {
  width: 30%; /*Change this to fit your design*/
}
.seq {
  display: inline;
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.seq .item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%; /*Change this to fit your design*/
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.seq .item:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 0.1em solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="seq">
    <div class="item item-title">A</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="seq">
    <div class="item item-title">B</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="seq">
    <div class="item item-title">C</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>

  <div class="seq">
    <div class="item item-title">D</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

About the AngularJS binding:
In your controller define your array of sequences and some functions to manipulate the sequences:

```
$scope.sequences = [];

$scope.addSequence = function(sequenceName){
  var newSequence = { name : sequenceName, events: [] };
  $scope.sequences.push(newSequence);
};

$scope.addEventToSequence = function(sequenceName, event){
  var sequence = getSequence(sequenceName);  // write this function to get the right sequence from the array
  sequence.events.push(event);
}
```

Now in your html loop over the sequences and events using ng-repeat

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="sequence in sequences">
    <ul>
      <li>{{sequence.name}}</li>
      <li ng-repeat="event in sequence.event">{{event.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```